# ORA-01795: maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000 error

Tags: sql, oracle, report

I need to add a parameter that has about 17000 values. And they constantly change. 
I want "all" to be the default value, but in that case I am unable to pass all 17,000 values in for the parameter due to `IN` lists being capped at 1,000 entries by the database.

When I try to pass all 17,000 values, I get an "ORA-01795: maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000" error.

I understand why Oracle doesn't allow more than that.  Is there a way to overcome this problem?

Comment: Where are the 17000 values coming from, and how are you supplying them to the query at the moment? If from another table you should be joining; if some external source than you can sue a collection, or if they're in a file maybe an external table or staging table.

Comment: Declare a temp table, load 17000 values into it, and do a join instead of using a gigantic IN clause.

Comment: Yes, there are multiple ways to accomplish that. Multiple parameters are one possibility then just use the multiple in-clauses to get around this.

Comment: @AlexPoole in my main query select * from abc where segment in (:segment)
then i create (segment) parameter as a menu type. and in list of values 

i have SELECT DISTINCT SEGMENT FROM  SUPPLIER<--17000 results

Comment: That sounds like you should just be joining `abc` to `segment`. Not sure what you mean by a menu type.

Comment: The 17000 values must come from somewhere : a user isn't going to type all those expressions into a GUI. So where do they come from? Can they not be stored in the database, in a table? Then the query becomes a simple join, as others have suggested. **edit** Just seen that @AlexPoole suggested this. So basically I agree with Alex :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not pass in all 17,000 values when you want all of them.  Do this instead.

```
select * 
from abc 
where (segment = :segment OR :segment IS NULL)
```

When the user does not select a segment parameter value, this will return data for all the segments.

If you want your front end to present "all" as a value, you could do this as a simple variation:

```
select * 
from abc 
where (segment = :segment OR nullif(:segment,'all') IS NULL)
```

Comment: You're welcome.  Kindly accept my answer if you are satisfied.  Do you mind if I edit your question a bit for clarity?